# Estimating strong scaling efficiency when single-node run is not possible

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, performance-testing, hpc, microbenchmark

I have implemented an OpenMP/MPI hybrid parallel algorithm, and would like to measure its strong-scaling parallel efficiency. For this, I would have to calculate speed-up `S=t(1)/t(N)`, and then the efficiency `E=S/N`.

**Background:** Having done some analysis, I was able to show that the peak efficiency of the algorithm could be expected at a problem size, at which the single node of my benchmark cluster *cannot house the data required*.

**Possible solutions:** I can either:

1. calculate speed-up using the smallest node-count, at which the data can be housed e.g. at 4 nodes => `S=t(4)/t(N)`, or,
2. calculate the theoretical single-node time-to-solution `t(1)` by extrapolation, and then use that value as reference.

**Questions:**

1. Which approach is better and why?
2. If I use the first approach, can I, strictly speaking, even refer to it as strong-scaling parallel efficiency, seeing as it doesn't conform to the definition provided above?

**Bonus question:** When we measure `t(1)`, should we run the algorithm with simulated communication calls (i.e. by calling `mpirun -n 1 ./my_benchmark_program`), or should we rather call a version of the program which performs no communication at all (i.e. `./my_openmp_only_benchmark_program`)?

I hope this post is clear, please ask for clarification if it isn't. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems with the classical definition of speedup if you are using MPI. The single processor case involves no communication, while the two-processor one does, so there is overhead in the `t(2)` case and it will *always* be less than twice as fast. This is even worse if you have a multicore/multinode setup, where up to 16 (or so) processes will run on a single node, so `t(17)` will suddenly be much slower because it starts involving a second node.

This means you can not simply apply the textbook formulas. You need to explain how you are doing your scalability study. For instance: one process per node until the number of processes == number of nodes, then start putting multple processes on each node, et cetera.

The fact that the single-process case does not fit in memory is then a minor hiccup: you start with a base case of multiple processes, and document that fact, plus your reasoning for the base case that you actually used.

Comment: After adequate documentation of your choice, would you still **call** it strong-scaling parallel efficiency in a scientific article?

Comment: Absolutely. There is nothing wrong with using a small process count as base case. As long as you can show a straight-ish line through a number of points.